# camera overlay Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error `"Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged "` on my cameraVC. I think it is since I am adding a overlay that is not attached in storyboard, but rather its own XIB file that is loaded in like so:

```
//set our custom overlay view
    ControlsViewController *overlayViewController = [[ControlsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControlsViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;
```

The overlay works but I get that error and also `Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.` when the camera comes on. Anyone seen this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"
This can occur when trying to present your view controller on a `UIViewControlleView` that is added with:

```
[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

With out setting the secondViewController as a child

```
[self addChildViewController:secondViewController];
```

Comment: so would I add `[self addChildViewController:overlayViewController];` before `self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;`

Comment: How is the ViewContoller that you add overlayViewController to added? When I have seen this its because Someone does [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view] then [secondViewController presentViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES completion^{}];